# How to read throughput-sampler sink values in spring-xd

Tags: spring-xd

Stream definition:
"http --port=9400 | throughput-sampler"

I've sent the START and END/ STOP payloads but I'm not sure how to read out the throughput values.

It doesn't show up in logs, so I'm wondering how do I access the values. There seems to be no documentations detailing it either.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug; add

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.xd.integration.throughput=INFO
```

to the

```
xd/config/xd-singlenode-logger.properties
```

or

```
xd/config/xd-container-logger.properties
```

depending on which topology you are using, and you'll see...

> 09:56:16,358 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO pool-10-thread-10 throughput.ThroughputSamplerMessageHandler - Throughput sampled for 2 items: 0/s in 5584ms elapsed time.

The default `endMessage` is `END`.